# How to provide new line in text file in android?

Tags: android, newline

I am writing a string in a text file of sd-card and it is working fine.
But I want to add New Line after every line.
Right now I am using this:

```
str.append("\r\n");
```

and

```
str.append("\n");
```

and

```
bufferedWriter.newLine();
```

But all of above are not working. Please give me a best solution.

Comment: How did you check whether it worked?

Comment: I use **"\n"** and it works just fine.

Comment: In that case, you'd write `\n\n`. The first `\n` ends the current line. The second one creates a new blank line.

Comment: @Vyger but my side it is not working...

Comment: @W.K.S I did use \n\n but not works

Comment: How can you day that it doesn't work? did you open the file with... notepad? If so, you will see a mess. Use a decent text editor, instead.

Comment: also you can try **System.getProperty("line.separator");**

Comment: @Vyger +1 for the Notepad remark. It's formatting is a total mess!

Comment: I open it in htmlViewer of android tab. It is working fine in notepad but not in htmlViewer.

Comment: You answered yourself. As the name suggests, **htmlViewer** is meant to show html files, so, it won't respect formatting.

Answer (score 0):

Please print your file after getting text into String Object then you wil **able to see new line**.

**Most of editor not able to decode new line charter that's why whenever you will try to see in editor, fill will show in a single line.**

I executed a similar program and it worked for me. I observed a strange behavior though. It added those new lines to the file, however the cursor remained at the first line. If you want to verify, write a String after your newline characters, you will see that the String is written just below those new lines.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the proposed solution that worked for me too -

```
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("dummy.txt",0));
BufferedWriter bwriter = new BufferedWriter(out);
// write the contents to the file
bwriter.write("String one");
bwriter.newLine();
```

Also, just try to add another string after the new line to confirm that the new line is added by doing like -

```
bwriter.write("String two");
```

You may see the above text in the new line.